# how to use sed from a tcl file

Tags: unix, sed, exec, tcl

I'm trying to use the Unix "sed" command form within a tcl file, like this:
(to change multiple spaces to one space)

```
exec /bin/sed 's/ \+/ /g' $file
```

I also tried `exec /bin/sed 's/ \\+/ /g' $file`  (an extra backslash)

none of the version work, and I get the error

```
/bin/sed: -e expression #1, char 1: Unknown command: `''
```

The command works fine when run from a linux terminal

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

What you're doing wrong is using `'` (single quote) characters. They're not special to Tcl *at all*. The equivalent in Tcl is enclosing a word in `{`braces`}`; it gives no special treatment at all to the characters inside. Thus, what you seek to do would be:

```
exec /bin/sed {s/ +/ /g} $file
```

Mind you, if you're doing something more complex and the restriction of Tcl to whole-words being unquoted, then you might instead go for this:

```
exec /bin/sh -c "sed 's/ +/ /g' $file"
```

Or, *real* idiomatic Tcl just doesn't use sed for something this simple:

```
set f [open $file]
set replacedContents [regsub -all { +} [read $f] " "]
close $f
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `exec /bin/sed "s/\ +/\ /g" $file`

The '\ ' tells TCL that there's an space there. Also using the '"' configures properly the string.

Comment: Simpler to do: exec /bin/sed {s/ +/ /g} $file
- quoting with {} in Tcl is equivalent to quoting with '' in the shell.