# Sed command does not execute correctly when called from bash script and works fine when called from prompt

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I have a function that reads through a file and, at specific lines, executes the command found on that line in the file. The function seemed to be working OK until I tried adding a *sed* command to a line, and then I ran into trouble. When the *sed* command should execute, I see the following error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command `''
```

In the file that I am executing commands from, the sed expression is:

```
sed -i 's# libcrypto.a##;s# libssl.a##' Makefile
```

At first, I thought that the issue could be resolved by following the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4123585/how-to-use-sed-from-a-tcl-file). However, after trying to rewrite the line in the file as `bash -c "sed -i 's# libcrypto.a##;s# libssl.a##' Makefile"`, I received the following error:

```
-i: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
-i: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

The function that should be executing these lines in the file looks like this:

```
OLD_IFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'
LABEL=($( cat /etc/file/containing/lines/to/execute ))
IFS=$OLD_IFS

for ((i=3; i <= $((${#LABEL[@]} - 1)); i++)); do # Start at i=3 to avoid three lines of comments at the beginning of the file.
    . . .
    if [[ "${LABEL[i]}" == some criteria ]]; then
        exec ${LABEL[i]} &> /dev/null &
    fi
done
```

What am I doing incorrectly?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you abbreviated something in your question?  Since `#` is the sed comment character, I would have thought that your `sed -i` line doesn't do what you seem to think it does..

Comment: Can you a) tell us your interactive shell, and b) what shell you have in the shabang line of your script?

Comment: @PaulHicks Since this is for building openssl for my LFS (Linux From Scratch) system, I was following the install directions found at http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/stable/postlfs/openssl.html.

Comment: @Tink a) My interactive shell is /bin/bash and b) what do you mean by "shabang line" of my script?

Comment: #!/.../... the first line of any normal shell-script that states which shell to use when invoked via /path/to/script, rather than e.g., bash script or sh script ...

Comment: My shabang line is `#!/bin/bash`. Thanks to you, I learned a new phrase (shebang line)!

Comment: If an MSWindows machine was involved in creating, copying or transfering  your script (ftp, or other), cleanup DOS lineending chars with `dos2unix myScript myscript2 ... myScriptN`. Good luck.

Comment: @shelter Windoze was not involved in any of those steps.

Comment: try `'s/...//;s/...//'` in place of `'s#...##;s#...##'`

Comment: @gboffi Thanks for the suggestion, but replacing the hastags with /'s results in the same error.

Comment: I can execute your `sed` command as posted within and outside of a bash script without any difference successfully. Can you post more of the bash script involved?

Comment: @nlu I have added the part of the script that is involved to my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have two solutions.

First one, in your file write

```
sed -i s#libcrypto.a##;s#libssl.a## Makefile
```

without the apices and without the spaces, in the edited `Makefile` you'll get two innocouos, I mean harmless, extra spaces.

The second one is to modify your function, the one that executes lines from the file, and using `eval $line` instead of using simply `$line` (my guess is that your function reads a line from the file, stores the result in a variable `line`, like in

```
while read line ; do
    ...
done < the_file_with_the_sed_command
```